# Laplacian centrality in bipartite weighted graphs

Tags: networkx, network-analysis, bipartite, weighted-graph, laplacian

I'm new to Network Analysis and I need to solve a doubt: is the Laplacian centrality measure applicable to bipartite graphs?
Specifically, I have a bipartite weighted graph. The issue is that I want to apply centrality measures considering the edge weights in the bipartite graphs. By projecting the graph I would lose the edge weight data.
I therefore applied laplacian_centrality by NetworkX directly to the bipartite graph in order to include the original edge weights in the measuring and I got reliable results. I was wondering if this application is correct or if it should be used the projection of the graph, thus losing the original edge weights.

LaplCentr=laplacian_centrality(G, weight='weight')
#referring to Networkx source code, I computed the Laplacian centrality this way